# Writing excel work books to Google Cloud Storage bucket using Google Cloud Composer

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-composer

I have a requirement where I have to create excel workbook (.xlsx) with 2 different workbooks. But when storing the data into GCS bucket, getting file not found error. I was able to save .csv files successfully. Please find the below example

```py
    import pandas as pd
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [4, 5, 6]
    af1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
    bf1 = pd.DataFrame(b)
    af1.columns = ['A']
    bf1.columns = ['B']
    with pd.ExcelWriter('gs://<bucket-name>/output.xlsx') as writer:
        af1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="A", index=False)
        bf1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="B", index=False)
```

But getting the file not found. Whereas if I try to write to a csv file (using .to_csv("samepath")), am able to see the file. Please help

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the bucket directly without using the [Google Cloud Storage API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python). This is not a recommended approach. So try to use the Google Cloud Storage API Client Libraries and follow the below steps for your requirement:

Step1: Add the [xlsxwriter](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/) package in Cloud Composer before triggering a DAG:

Environment details -> PYPI Packages -> Edit -> Package Name -> Type `xlsxwriter` -> Click Save

Step2: Try the below code:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils import timezone
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

def invoke_cloud_storage():
   a = [1, 2, 3]
   b = [4, 5, 6]
   af1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
   bf1 = pd.DataFrame(b)
   af1.columns = ['A']
   bf1.columns = ['B']
   writer=pd.ExcelWriter('file-name.xlsx')
   af1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="A", index=False)
   bf1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="B", index=False)
   writer.save()
   storage_client = storage.Client()

   bucket = storage_client.bucket('bucket-name')
   blob = bucket.blob('file-name.xlsx')

   blob.upload_from_filename('file-name.xlsx')

with DAG(
   'pandas_storage',
   description='Upload file in Cloud Storage',
   schedule_interval=None,
   start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
   max_active_runs=1,
   catchup=False
) as dag:

   # Invoke cloud run
   process_file = PythonOperator(
       task_id='invoke_cloud_storage',
       python_callable=invoke_cloud_storage,
       dag=dag
   )

process_file
```

If you still need to access the bucket without using Google Cloud Storage API Client Libraries, add [gcsfs](https://pypi.org/project/gcsfs/) and [fsspec](https://pypi.org/project/fsspec/) libraries as dependencies in Cloud Composer. But these two libraries are not managed by Google and this is not a recommended approach, use it at your own risk. Follow the below steps for your requirement:

Step1: Add the `xlsxwriter`, `gcsfs` and `fsspec` packages in Cloud Composer before triggering a DAG:

Environment details -> PYPI Packages -> Edit -> Add Packages -> Click Save.

[image]

Step2 : Try the below code:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils import timezone
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

def invoke_cloud_storage():
   a = [1, 2, 3]
   b = [4, 5, 6]
   af1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
   bf1 = pd.DataFrame(b)
   af1.columns = ['A']
   bf1.columns = ['B']
   with pd.ExcelWriter('gs://bucket-name/file-name.xlsx') as writer:
       af1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="A", index=False)
       bf1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="B", index=False)

with DAG(
   'pandas_storage_nr',
   description='Upload file in Cloud Storage',
   schedule_interval=None,
   start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
   max_active_runs=1,
   catchup=False
) as dag:

   # Invoke cloud run
   process_file = PythonOperator(
       task_id='invoke_cloud_storage',
       python_callable=invoke_cloud_storage,
       dag=dag
   )

process_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a file as a memory stream and after you can save in the bucket using the library gcsfs.

Let me show an example.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import gcsfs

credential_file = 'credential.json'

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
af1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
bf1 = pd.DataFrame(b)
af1.columns = ['A']
bf1.columns = ['B']

file_stream = io.BytesIO() 

with pd.ExcelWriter(file_stream, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    af1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="A", index=False)
    bf1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="B", index=False)
    
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=__project_id,
                            storage_options={"token": __credentials})

with fs.open('gs://<bucket-name>/output.xlsx', "wb") as f:
    f.write(file_stream.getbuffer())
```